# android:id of View in xml and view.getId()

Tags: java, android, xml

Sorry for stupid question, but is there some correspondence between `android:id` for view and `view.getId()`? Of course, they are different, of `String` and `int` type respectively. I know that `android:id` can be obtained in java code via `findViewById(R.id.name)`, where `name` is `android:id`, but I couldn't find value of `view.getId()` in xml file.

### Correction

`android:id` is used in java code via `findViewById(R.id.name), this method returns view itself.

Answer (score 1):

So, In xml what you put as `id` is an string identifier not actual value, Actual value is automatically generated and stored as `Constant int` in `R` file. Find this file in

```
Module->build->generated->source->r-><build_type>->R.java
```

`View.getId()` returns the same value as stored in R file.

So the conclusion is:

- Value present in `xml` is a constant identifier, actual value resides in `R.java` file.
- `view.getId()` returns the actual value that is there in R not the constant string value.

Answer (score 1):

Your `view.getId()` gets the Id that Android manage in the background, is a unique number to know the item. Your Id in the XML file is a name that you give to that item to refer it in your Code, its a friendly name to that item.

When you do `findViewById(R.id.your_friendly_name)` you are getting the View itSelf.

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks everybody who answer my stupid question. Correspondence between android:id and view.getId is given by `Module->build->generated->source->r-><build_type>-><package>-> R.java`, as Nayan Srivastava said (special thanks to him).

Answer (score 0):

view.getId() returns the integer Id generated in the R.java file, this is generated after processing your xml file.

> I know that android:id can be obtained in java code via findViewById(R.id.name)

wrong you dont get the android:id, infact you get the view itself.

Comment: Khan, thanks. Of course, `getViewById` retuns view itself, correction to answer is added.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked fine for me in getting the `id` of a XML file from the XML folder

```
int xmlFileId = getResources().getIdentifier("filename", "xml", getPackageName());
```

The `xmlFileId` has your file id, which is the `"filename"` without `.xml`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).